# Calculate TF-IDF of Loughran and Bill McDonald dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I am exploring the financial-related [dictionary](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ECPJMxV2wSalXG8ykMmkpa1fq_ur0Rf/view) of Loughran and McDonald. 
I want to calculate the TF-IDF weighting of the words within the dictionary. I use the following formula, based on the [paper](https://www.uts.edu.au/sites/default/files/ADG_Cons2015_Loughran%20McDonald%20JE%202011.pdf) "When Is a Liability Not a Liability":

[image]

**Q1:** Which value should I use for *N* (the total number of 10-Ks in the sample)? If I use the cleaned (50,115) or the raw (121,217) number of 10-Ks, I get negative values for some words. For example, the word “almost” has a value of 126,738 for Doc Count. However, `log(121,217 / 126,738)` yields a negative value which is not possible.

**Q2:** What does column E and F of the master dictionary represent? Are these values equal to *tfi,j* the raw count of the *i*th word in the *j*-th document, and *aj* the average word count in the document (page 42 in the paper)?

Thank you

Comment: Look up the principles in [this standard textbook](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/). You can't get an IDF if you have only one document.